# Constrained filter design

Tags: power-spectral-density, finite-impulse-response

I have a desired filter magnitude response, i.e. $|H(j\omega)|$. How can I find the time-domain coefficients of a filter $h=[h_0, h_1, ..., h_{L-1}]$ that has a similar magnitude response such that $h_0=1$?

Comment: Why "constrained"?

Comment: This is in the contest of noise shaping where $h_0=1$ is inherent. The actual filter coefficients are $h_1$ to $h_{L-1}$.